# Is it possible to insert pieces of RTF text into a Word document (.docx) using OpenXml?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I'm developing a .NET C# app that needs to create a Word document, inserting fragments of RTF text which are stored in a database. Does anyone know if it is possible and how this is done using OpenXml (or COM interop)?

I don't need to convert one complete RTF file into a Word document. I need to programatically create a Word document and add pieces of RTF text in different places in the word document using C#.

Comment: Do you mean docx? OpenXml can create a document.  I would use OpenXml over COM interop.

Comment: I would prefer to use OpenXml over COM interop too but I don't know if it's possible to insert pieces of RTF text into the OpenXml document without needing to parse it first. If anybody can point me in the right direction that would be nice. Or if it can be done with Xaml (using a flowdocument) that's also fine for me, Than I will use a WPF RichTextBox instead of a WinForms RichTextBox to insert the pieces of text into the DB.

Answer (score 6):

You can import external content via the *altChunk* anchor.
The *altChunk* anchor defines a place within a word document to insert
external content such as RTF, HTML, XML, ...

For more information about the *altChunk* anchor please refer to
the following [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk%28v=office.15%29.aspx) article.

The following code shows how to insert a chunk of RTF into a word document using the
OpenXML SDK:

1. Open your word document.
2. Create an `AlternativeFormatImportPart` chunk with a unique chunk ID.
3. Feed your RTF data into the chunk (I'm using a `MemoryStream` here).
4. Create an `AltChunk` with the same ID used to create the `AlternativeFormatImportPart`.
5. Save the word document.

.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"test.docx", true))
  {
    string altChunkId = "AltChunkId5";

    MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
    AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainDocPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
        AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Rtf, altChunkId);                

    string rtfEncodedString = @"{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard This is some {\b bold} text.\par}";

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(val)))
    {
      chunk.FeedData(ms);
    }

    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
    altChunk.Id = altChunkId;

    mainDocPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(
      altChunk, mainDocPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());

    mainDocPart.Document.Save();

  }
}
```