# Sending Swedish and Chinese signs to Docx using OpenXML and RTF

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, rtf

### Goal

Passing Swedish and Chinese signs to a DocX-file in a RTF format.<sup>[2]</sup>

### Description

I need to dynamically generate a RTF-formatted string containing Swedish and Chinese signs and send it to an existing Docx-file. I have managed to handle the Swedish diaereses (åäö) but I can't manage to get the Chinese signs to be shown properly, instead they are shown as ????

```
    private void buttonSendDiaeresesToDocx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        var filename = @"SpecialCharactersInDocx.docx";
        var filepath = Path.Combine(desktop, filename);

        //Dynamic content fetched from the database.
        var content = "This should be Swedish and Chinese signs -> åäö - 部件名称";

        var rtfEncodedString = new StringBuilder();
        rtfEncodedString.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard ");
        rtfEncodedString.Append(content);
        rtfEncodedString.Append(@"\par}");

        removeExistingFile(filepath);
        createEmptyDocx(filepath);

        addRtfToWordDocument(filepath, rtfEncodedString.ToString());

        openDocx(filepath);
    }

    private void addRtfToWordDocument(string filepath, string rtfEncodedString)
    {
        //Implemented as suggested at
        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/14861397/1997617

        using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true))
        {
            string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";

            MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
            AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainDocPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Rtf, altChunkId);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rtfEncodedString)))
            {
                chunk.FeedData(ms);
            }

            AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
            altChunk.Id = altChunkId;

            mainDocPart.Document.Body.ReplaceChild(
              altChunk, mainDocPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());

            mainDocPart.Document.Save();
        }
    }
```

I have tried to use different encodings for the memory stream (Default, ASCII, UTF8, GB18030, ...) but none seams to work. I've also tried to convert the encoding of the *rtfEncodedString* variable before passing it to the *addRtfToWordDocument* method.

**How do I make both the Swedish and the Chinese signs to show properly in the document?**

### Notes and references

1. The above code snippet is the part of my solution that I think is relevant for the question. The entire code sample can be downloaded at http://www.bjornlarsson.se/externals/SpecialCharactersInDocx02.zip
2. The RTF format is needed in the real world application since the content is to be shown as a table (with bold text) in the document.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirement to use RTF. If all you want is to insert boldfaced text you could do that using OpenXML as well – and, by the way, a very well written question!

Comment: @DirkVollmar
* The Docx generated by the attached solution opens for me (Visual Stuido 2015/MS Word 2013). Do You get any errors?
* The reason for using RTF is to insert data as a table into the document.

Comment: @Jo. I'm not quite sure I understand what you are suggesting. Could you elaborate? Changing MemoryStream to FileStream causes an exception since the file is already opened. Or did you mean to write the RTF to a separate file and then read from that file? The latter doesn't give ???? but the signs are still not correct.

Comment: After i downloaded your code i see i doesn't make sense with the filestream but i tried something else see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use wordpad to create the rtf string for you. Open wordpad copy your content save to file. And then use a texteditor to read the rtf.
your rtf string then looks like this :

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Consolas;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Consolas;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset134 SimSun;}{\f3\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.10586}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs19\lang7 This should be Swedish and Chinese signs -> \f1\'e5\'e4\'f6 - \f2\'b2\'bf\'bc\'fe\'c3\'fb\'b3\'c6\f3\fs22\par
}
```

maybe it helps.I tested the rtf string with your code and it works!

Dynamic generate rtf string via richtextbox :

```
private void buttonSendDiaeresesToDocx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            var filename = @"SpecialCharactersInDocx.docx";
            var filepath = Path.Combine(desktop, filename);

            removeExistingFile(filepath);
            createEmptyDocx(filepath);
            rtfEncodedString = new StringBuilder();
            string contentOriginal = "This should be Swedish and Chinese signs -> åäö - 部件名称";
            string rtfStart =
                "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1031{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\\f1\\fmodern\\fprq6\\fcharset134 SimSun;}}\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\f0\\fs17 ";
            RichTextBox rtfBox = new RichTextBox {Text = contentOriginal};
            string content = rtfBox.Rtf;
            content = content.Replace(rtfStart, "");
            rtfEncodedString.Append(rtfStart);
            rtfEncodedString.Append(content);
            rtfEncodedString.Append(@"\par}");
            addRtfToWordDocument(filepath, rtfEncodedString.ToString());

            openDocx(filepath);
        }
```

Comment: Ah, I think I see the confusion. The RTF string needs to be dynamically generated because in the real world application it will contain a RTF formatted table with text fetched from the database. I didn't include that part when i simplified the code since my problem was related to the viewing in the Docx file and not to the fetching of the data.

Comment: Then how you generate your rtf?

Comment: I generate the RTF string with a StringBuilder to which I add the dynamic content and the RTF structure for the table. I have updated the code in my question to better reflect this. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Updated my answer maybe you can use the code to populate your tablecells.