# DocX ReplaceText using rich text from Xceed's WPF Toolkit

Tags: c#, richtextbox, docx, wpftoolkit, xceed

Unable to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, I'm using [Xceed DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/docx) to take data from WPF fields and write them to a Word file. I need to replace a `«field»` in a Word file with the text and formatting from a [RTB](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/RichTextBox). If I use something simple like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces field location with given formatted text
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mergeField">Target location</param>
/// <param name="textToWrite">Rich, formatted text to process and insert</param>
public static void FindReplaceRich(string mergeField, string textToWrite)
{
    while (document.FindAll(mergeField).Count > 0)
    {
        document.ReplaceText("«" + mergeField + "»", textToWrite);                
    }
}
```

The code above is used for unformatted text and so in this instance my Word file gets a silly, RTF blurb added right onto the document like so: *{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red124\green252\blue0;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs18\f0\cf0 \cf0\ql{\f0 {\ltrch This is }{\highlight2\ltrch really }{\ltrch dumb. }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
}
}*

**So how do I process this rich text so I can insert it into my Word file using Xceed's DocX library?**

So far I've tried using the Clibboard [as described here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/224990/richtextbox-to-ms-word-with-formatting) but I'm not sure if I'm copying the text correctly or how I go about applying the pasted content. I'm also trying to use DocX's `InsertParagraph` but that just looks like it appends a paragraph to the document (and I still haven't solved the formatting issue). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not worth the trouble. Dump DocX and pickup [Open XML SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711659/is-it-possible-to-insert-pieces-of-rtf-text-into-a-word-document-docx-using-o).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace tags by values, I recommend you to use a "templating engine" for docx. I happen to have created one myself : https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater

With the open-source version, you will mostly be fine if you want to replace tags by simple text or do loops/conditions (other advanced features such as HTML insertion are paid extensions).