# How can I programmatically insert RTF text into a PowerPoint text frame using C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, powerpoint, vsto

Is there any way to programmatically insert RTF-formatted text into a PowerPoint TextFrame?

```
string myString = <some RTF formatted text>;

MyPlaceholder.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = myString;
```

This answer gets me close: [Is it possible to insert pieces of RTF text into a Word document (.docx) using OpenXml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711659/is-it-possible-to-insert-pieces-of-rtf-text-into-a-word-document-docx-using-o)

But I am having trouble figuring out how to do this in PowerPoint rather than Word.

What I am trying to do is copy text from a RichEditBox in my application onto a PowerPoint slide and maintain font-color, format, etc. I am able to successfully bring the text into PowerPoint. I just can't bring in the formatting (such as font-color) with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you development UWP app?

Comment: Yes, it is a UWP app. Thanks

Comment: UWP does not provide api to edit powerpoint file directly, you could search third part library to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry, Nico, I should have said that I am using an AppService to interface with PowerPoint from UWP. I then use VSTO to create the PowerPoint presentation. I have it correctly bringing text into the PowerPoint slides, but I am unable to get PowerPoint to bring in RTF-formatted text and maintain font-color, formatting, etc.) The text comes from a RichEditBox in my application and I need to duplicate the formatting in the RichEdit box on a PowerPoint slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to accomplish this by saving from the RichEditBox to a stream using the following line of code and then writing to a file:

```
tempRichEditBox.Document.SaveToStream(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, randAccStream);
```

I then used this line to import the file into PowerPoint. The font color and formatting are maintained.

```
var rtfShape = PptSlide.Shapes.AddOLEObject(FileName: rtfFileName);
```